# How to generate random number to express the probability

Tags: java, algorithm

I don't know how to make it in JAVA.
Sorry everybody. My case is with 51% probability, I have to do something. and, with 49% probability, I don't have to do anything.
I think I need to generate a random number, which will reference, express the probability.

how can I make it suitable to my case in Java? Thank you in advanced!

Comment: Do you want to generate random values between 0 and 1?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Generating random integers in a range with Java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/363681/generating-random-integers-in-a-range-with-java)

Comment: `new Random().nextInt(2) == 0`

Comment: @JaroslawPawlak  - What's wrong with `new Random().nextDouble()`?

Comment: google Math.random() java.

Comment: @VinodMadyalkar You need to do division afterwards :)

Comment: @JaroslawPawlak - Why does he need to do division if he gets a value between 0 and 1? :)

Comment: @VinodMadyalkar Ah, you are right, my mistake. It somehow seems simpler to me when the random can return one of two possible values instead of checking whether the return value is lower than the average, and we when we have infinite number of possibilities. But you are right, `nextDouble()` will work fine here.

Comment: plz read again my case. I edited my question in order to make it obvious. thank u!

Comment: @JaroslawPawlak - Yes. That makes sense.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the [`Random`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Random.html) class. It has methods such as `Random.nextInt` where you can give it an upper bound and it will give you a random number between 0 (inclusive) and that number (exclusive). There are also other methods like `Random.nextBoolean` which returns 50% chance of `true` or `false`.

Comment: so If the chance is 49% and 51% then how to I make it ?

Comment: @MyWill I would use `Random.nextDouble` for that. `if (new Random().nextDouble()<=.51){}`

Comment: if (r.nextInt(99) < 51) { .. }

Comment: Yup you can also go the `nextInt` way like @Rustam has mentioned.

Comment: @MyWill glad I was able to help. Feel free to accept my answer so it can help other SO users. :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use Math.random function alternatively. The tutorial is [here](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/lang/math_random.htm)

Quoting javadoc.

```
Returns a double value with a positive sign, greater than or equal to 0.0 and less than 1.0. Returned values are chosen pseudorandomly with (approximately) uniform distribution from that range.
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to generate integer then you can use `nextInt()` method like this -

```
 Random randomGenerator = new Random();
 for (int i = 1; i <= 10; ++i){
   int randomInt = randomGenerator.nextInt(100);
   System.out.println("Generated : " + randomInt);
 }
```

If you want double you can use `nextDouble()` method -

```
 Random randomGenerator = new Random();
 for (int i = 1; i <= 10; ++i){
   int randomInt = randomGenerator.nextDouble(100);
   System.out.println("Generated : " + randomInt);
 }
```

And if you want to generate random between a range then you can do -

```
int shift=0;
int range=6;
Random ran = new Random();
int x = ran.nextInt(range) + shift;
```

This code will generate random number (int) upto 6 (from 0 to 5). If you want to generate random number shifting the lower limit then you can change the `shif` value. For example changing the `shift` to `2` will give you all random number greater than or equal 2.